# PyCharm not making suggestions for numpy array returned by a method on another numpy array

Tags: pycharm

This is the code I have in my editor:

```
import numpy

arr = numpy.random.randint(0, 2, size=10)
walk = numpy.cumsum(arr)
```

When I type `arr.` PyCharm will suggest me numpy methods:
[image]

However, I am not so lucky with walk:
[image]

Why is PyCharm not suggesting methods for walk, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm only displays the correct menu if it can guess the type, or if the function itself is annotated. To get around the issue, you can annotate manually:

Python 3.6 / Pylint annotations:

```
walk : numpy.array = numpy.cumsum(arr)
```

Python 2 annotations:

```
walk = numpy.cumsum(arr) # type:numpy.array
```

You could also provide a stub, annotating the function itself:

```
def cumsum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None) -> array:
```

For more details, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/type-hinting-in-product.html